# Span not growing with child size

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to put two components on the same line and have wrapped it like this. I am trying to keep this as reusable as possible and so I am trying to get as general of a solution as possible.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="component-parent">
        <label for="driversLicense.num">Driver's License #</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="driversLicense.num"></input>
    </span>
    <span class="component-parent">
        <label for="driversLicense.state">State</label>
         <select id="driversLicense.state" class="form-control"></select>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: block;
}
.component-parent {
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

The width: 100% is inherited from Bootstrap and if I remove it it cause all kinds of problems with rest of my layout.

The problem is the `input` is underneath the `select` and I would like them to have a little bit of space in between them. If I remove `width: 100%` then it looks correct and if I remove my padding then the two components touch with no space in between them but then my insertion point is in the wrong place.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/graHw/4/) showing the phenomena.

Is there some way to change the CSS of the `form-group` that will solve this problem? I can add an additional container(s) if need be but I would rather not change the CSS or html of either of the `component-parent` elements or their children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new `span` in between the two `component-parent` elements. The span has a `margin-left` that is equal to the horizontal padding.

Here is the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/graHw/7/)

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with the padding you were applying to the select! I added

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

which solved this problem, you will however need to float the spans to clear the gap!

Let me know if you have another question! :) all the best!

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/graHw/6/

Comment: This answer gave me some more google terms so I am up voting, but it changes the css of the one of the component-parent elements.

Comment: Glad it could be of some use, I'll try to think of a solution that doesn't! :)